# Oracle Apex Conditionally Display Form Fields

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Oracle 11g
apex 4.2.6.00.03

I have a form, where I need to conditionally display sections under specific condition

these sections fields are Skills and Clearance. However I only need these to show if the 
client requires to see them.

I have a LOV select list which gives,

- None,1
- Skills Only,2
- Clearance Only,3
- Clearance and Skills,4

page items are P192_skill and P192_Clearance

Then once selected then show the specific fields based on there selection.

Answer (score 2):

Create an onchange dynamic action that shows/hides fields based on the value selected - using a JavaScript expression. If more than true/false condition present, you can execute a JavaScript action that utilises supplied APIs like `$x_Show()`

See the Oracle Application Express API Reference, Non-namespace JavaScript APIs documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/GUID-B4DC6729-ED57-49F1-B18C-1EB1053E7421.htm#AEAPI277 (OP version)

http://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/Non-namespace-Javascript-APIs.htm#AEAPI-GUID-464EC395-C8B2-4B2C-A9A2-01D1E3964D41 (current APEX version, always handy to use current documentation to see approaching features, changing trends, future deprecations, ...)